# I want to group the table by 'Concept_CKI' column but need only 'Description' column in my final output with sum of 'Total Column'

Tags: sql

I have created a 3 column table, wherein I want to group the table by 'Concept_CKI' column but need only 'Description' column in my final output with sum of 'Total Column'

```
  select C.DESCRIPTION,COUNT(DISTINCT A.ENCNTR_ID) as 'Total',c.CONCEPT_CKI
  from [HIM_Clinical].[dbo].[APPOINTMENT_DATA] A
  LEFT JOIN [ODS_CCL].[dbo].[ODS_CCL_CODING] C ON A.ENCNTR_ID=C.ENCNTR_ID 
  AND SOURCE='PowerChart' 
  AND CAST(DIAGNOSIS_ADDED_DT AS DATE)>='2021-01-03' 
  AND CAST(DIAGNOSIS_ADDED_DT AS DATE)<='2021-01-09'
  and CAST(DIAGNOSIS_ADDED_DT AS DATE)=a.APPOINTMENT_DATE
  WHERE A.ENCNTR_TYPE='Virtual Consultation'
  AND A.HealthCenter_APPT LIKE '%Virtual%'
  AND Appointment_Status='Checked Out'
  --and c.CONCEPT_CKI='SNOMED!44054006'
  And APPOINTMENT_DATE>='2021-01-03' and APPOINTMENT_DATE<='2021-01-09'
  GROUP BY C.DESCRIPTION,c.CONCEPT_CKI
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
DESCRIPTION              Total      CONCEPT_KPI
Vitamin B12 level         4         SNOMED!365604004   
Deficiency Vitamin B12    5         SNOMED!365604004
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```
DESCRIPTION      Total
Vitamin B12        9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since description field can have different values for a single 'Concept_CKI' you can achieve your result by removing description from group by clause and use sub query to get the first description for any concept_cki. Please try below code.

```
select (select top (1) DESCRIPTION from [ODS_CCL_CODING] cc where cc.concept_cki=c.concept_cki) ,COUNT(DISTINCT A.ENCNTR_ID) as 'Total'
  from [HIM_Clinical].[dbo].[APPOINTMENT_DATA] A
  LEFT JOIN [ODS_CCL].[dbo].[ODS_CCL_CODING] C ON A.ENCNTR_ID=C.ENCNTR_ID 
  AND SOURCE='PowerChart' 
  AND CAST(DIAGNOSIS_ADDED_DT AS DATE)>='2021-01-03' 
  AND CAST(DIAGNOSIS_ADDED_DT AS DATE)<='2021-01-09'
  and CAST(DIAGNOSIS_ADDED_DT AS DATE)=a.APPOINTMENT_DATE
  WHERE A.ENCNTR_TYPE='Virtual Consultation'
  AND A.HealthCenter_APPT LIKE '%Virtual%'
  AND Appointment_Status='Checked Out'
  --and c.CONCEPT_CKI='SNOMED!44054006'
  And APPOINTMENT_DATE>='2021-01-03' and APPOINTMENT_DATE<='2021-01-09'
  GROUP by c.CONCEPT_CKI
```

Comment: The naming convention is different (for Vitamin B12) but, both are the same, as the 'concept_kpi' code is same and unique.

Comment: so I want to group it by concept_kpi code and it is okay if it picks up the 1st description name

Comment: Then, you need to have one description for all the rows containing same cocenpt_kpi. Right?

Comment: yes exactly....but in my final output i dont want to show concept_kpi column

Comment: Please share your table structure and some sample values. So that, I can test the query before suggesting you.

Comment: DESCRIPTION                Total           CONCEPT_CKI
Vitamin B12 level                   1            SNOMED!365604004
Vitamin B12 deficiency           4            SNOMED!365604004
Type 2 diabetes mellitus          25             SNOMED!44054006
Diabetes mellitus type II          3           SNOMED!44054006
Diabetes mellitus type2         29          SNOMED!44054006
URTI                                     9          SNOMED!54150009
Upper respiratory infection 3           SNOMED!54150009